# Verification and validation of a requirement spec (following B. Boehm's paper)

Tags: terminology, requirements-validation, validation

The purpose of this question is for me to understand the concept, I am well aware in practice I just do these things, regardless of how I call them.

Also, the famous paper from B. Boehm ([GUIDELINES FOR VERIFYING AND VALIDATING SOFTWARE REQUIREMENTS AND DESIGN SPECIFICATIONS](http://csse.usc.edu/TECHRPTS/1979/usccse79-501/usccse79-501.pdf)) makes a super clear distinction between validation and verification:

> By definition, verification involves the comparison between the
>   requirements baseline and the successive refinements descending from
>   it—the product design, detailed design, code, database, and
>   documentation--in order to keep these refinements consistent with the
>   requirements baseline. **Thus, verification activities begin in the
>   Product Design phase and conclude with the acceptance Test. They do not lead to changes in the requirements baseline; only to
>   changes in the refinements descending from it.**
>
> On the other hand, **validation identifies problems which must be
>   resolved by a change of the requirements specification**. For example, a
>   simulation of the product design may establish not only that the
>   design cannot meet the baseline performance requirements
>   (verification), but also that the performance requirements are too
>   stringent for any cost-effective product designs, and therefore need
>   to be changed (validation).

So far, so good - whenever I check anything against the requirements specification, I verify.

Therefore, requirement specification itself cannot be verified (as it would be compared to itself), and it is only validated - this is explicitly mentioned in the paper too:

> This refers to the requirements specification which is developed and
>   validated during the Plans and Requirements Phase, accepted by the
>   customer and developer at the Plans and Requirements Review as the
>   basis for the software development contract, and formally
>   change-controlled thereafter.

So I thought I had understood it well. In the next section, the paper presents V&V Criteria for requirements and design specs, with the first one being Completeness:

1. No TBDs
2. No references to non-existing functions, inputs or outputs
3. No missing spec. items
   ...

Then it reads that the first two can be **verified** automatically, while the other need to be **verified** or **validated** with some human intuition.

And here comes my confusion: Say I have received a requirement spec to be **validated**. So I start working and notice a reference to a non-existent element and also a statement "to be determined". Now, the paper speaks about **verification** of these properties but req.spec is only validated (as there is nothing to be verified against). How should I interpret it?

EDIT: I start to think that probably the author just did not want to repeat "verify or validate" all the time, as the whole section is called "V&V Criteria" and he made it clear earlier that requirements are validated, while successive documents are verified.

Comment: I like that you've put so much thought in to this... but what's the question?

Comment: @trashpanda Well, I tried to put in the last paragraph. If requirement specifications are just validated (as they have nothing to be verified against), why checking for TBDs or references to non-existing items is explicitly called verifying when this is something that surely can be done with requirements specs too?